# Exchange MS v2.0 Exporting to CSV -append Error

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to import a list of users, get mailbox permissions and export results to a .csv file. If i have just one name in the input file it works as soon as I have multiple it does not.If I use -append it errors (I believe it is cause I am using version 2.0 of PS EMS) any suggestions?

```
$users = get-content “mailboxusers.txt”
foreach ($user in $users) {
Get-MailboxPermission -identity $user | where {$_.user.tostring() -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false} | Export-Csv MailboxAccess.csv;
}
```

Comment: What version of Exchange are you on.  2010 only works with PowerShell 2.0.  Your code is working in my Exchange 2013 environment PoSh 5.1.  We could probably work around it with an implicit remoting session.  Let me know.

Comment: build a list by adding items to it in your `foreach` loop. then, after the loop is finished, export the collection to your csv.